# Training an OpenCV LBP Classifier

Tags: c++, opencv, classification

I need to create my own LBP Cascade Classifier using OpenCV, so to get used to the process, I have been using a very small file set, to get the hang of it.

However, I am struggling to find decent information on opencv_traincascade.  I set the process running on 87 positive images that were in a .vec file.  I realize this is a tiny set and will not be of much use, but I was hoping it might be enough to pickup one of my positive images if I pasted it exactly onto a negative, just to test the theory.
However, when I started the training process, the result was that it got to stage 5 and then hung when starting stage 6.

I restarted the process with an even smaller positive set and it did the same thing - for some reason it gets to stage x and freezes on the Neg Count at the start of a training stage, and never recovers.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?  Is the problem the tiny size of my training set?

```
===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
BEGIN
POS count : consumed   6 : 6
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    2600 : 1
Precalculation time: 10.965
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        0|
+----+---------+---------+
END

===== TRAINING 1-stage =====
BEGIN
POS count : consumed   6 : 6
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    2600 : 0.0244943
Precalculation time: 10.985
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        0|
+----+---------+---------+
END

===== TRAINING 2-stage =====
BEGIN
POS count : consumed   6 : 6
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    2600 : 0.000697076
Precalculation time: 11.237
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|0.000384615|
+----+---------+---------+
END

===== TRAINING 3-stage =====
BEGIN
POS count : consumed   6 : 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in the process of doing something similiar. The train stage can often get locked in a infinite loop and the code needs to be modified to prevent this condition. What parameters are you using for **createsamples** and **traincascade**? Try reducing the number of negative images in traincascade initially. This worked for me..

Comment: That explains a lot!  The createsamples parameters were: opencv_createsamples -img "image.png" -num 100 -bg "NegativeImages\bg.txt" -vec "samples.vec" -maxxangle 0.6 -maxyangle 0 -maxzangle 0.3 -maxidev 100 -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -w 118 -h 20 <br/> and the traincascade was:  opencv_traincascade -data "Data" -vec "samples.vec" -bg "NegativeImages\bg.txt" -numPos 100 -numNeg 400 -w 118 -h 20 -featureType LBP    It did seem to work better when I reduced the ratio of positive to negative samples.  Have you made the necersary code changes?